# Использовать Enum для наполнения массива или же напрямую для рандомного выбора нужных значений

Tags: java, массивы, строки, случайные-числа, enum

каким образом вызывать рандомно данные с Enum (типичные английские фамилии). Используется для выбора рандомной фамилии американцу. Или создать массив заполнить его из Enum

```
public enum Surname {
    Smith,
    Johnson,
    Williams,
    Jones,
    Brown,
    Davis,
    Miller,
    Wilson
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так можно заполнить список и вывести из enum:

```
List<Surname> enumValues = Arrays.asList(Surname.values());
    
for(Surname val : enumValues) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

---

или

```
List<String> enumNames = Stream.of(Enum.values())
                               .map(Surname::name)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Соответственно если есть список, то рандомное значение оттуда взять, думаю, не проблема

Например

```
Random rand = new Random();
System.out.println(enumValues.get(rand.nextInt(enumValues.size())));
```

Answer (score 0):

попробывал так. Переписую код))

```
final String[] studentsSurname = new String[Surname.values().length];{
        for (int i = 0; i < Surname.values().length; i++)
            studentsSurname[i] = Surname.values()[i].toString(); }

    public Student toCreateStudent() {
        Student student = new Student();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        student.surname = studentsSurname[rnd.nextInt(studentsSurname.length)];
```